# What to put in my if statement

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, time, timer

Ok so I have created a game and it works perfectly, except I don't want the player to win after just one defeat I want him to have to kill 10 enemies well I created my spawnmore method and I know the problem I just don't know how to fix it, in my if statement I have it saying if(dead < 10) then do my stuff, when I only want it to do it once every time dead increments one if you get what I mean here's my method thanks

```
public void spawnMore(){
        int delay = 1000;


        Timer time = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                if(WizardCells[BadGuy.getx()][BadGuy.gety()].getIcon() != null){
                    return;
                }


                if(WizardCells[BadGuy.getx()][BadGuy.gety()].getIcon() == null){
                    dead += 1;
                }

                if(dead < 10){
                    int where = (int)(10 + Math.random() *9);
                    BadGuy.spawnEnemy(where, where);
                    move();

                }
            }
        });
        time.start();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you could just move the if statement inside the previous if statement:

```
public void spawnMore(){
    int delay = 1000;


    Timer time = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if(WizardCells[BadGuy.getx()][BadGuy.gety()].getIcon() != null){
                return;
            }


            if(WizardCells[BadGuy.getx()][BadGuy.gety()].getIcon() == null){
                dead += 1;

                if(dead < 10){
                    int where = (int)(10 + Math.random() *9);
                    BadGuy.spawnEnemy(where, where);
                    move();
                }
            }

        }
    });
    time.start();


}
```